# why echo return value ($?) after pipeline always return "0"

Tags: shell, echo, pipeline

I realize the fact but I don't know why:

```
cat abc | echo $?
```

if `abc` does not exist, but above command still return `0`. Anyone knows the theory about why?

Comment: IMHO, the OP asks "why the cat does not the previous command"? (it is before echo... ;)

Comment: Are you asking why `echo $?` returns 0, or why it outputs the string `0`?  It returns 0 because it succeeds.  It outputs zero because its argument is the string `0`, which is what the shell expanded `$?` to, which happened because the command (simple command or pipeline or list) prior to this returned 0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why it *must* be this way is that a pipeline is made of processes running simultaneously. `cat`'s exit code can't possibly be passed to `echo` as an argument because arguments are set when the command begins running, and `echo` begins running before `cat` has finished.

`echo` doesn't take input from stdin, so `echo` on the right side of a pipe character is always a mistake.

**UPDATE:**

Since it is now clear that you are asking about a real problem, not just misunderstanding what you saw, I tried it myself. I get what I think is the correct result (1) from a majority of shells I tried (dash, zsh, pdksh, posh, and bash 4.2.37) but 0 from bash 4.1.10 and ksh (Version JM 93u+ 2012-02-29).

I assume the change in bash's behavior between versions is intentional, and the 4.1.x behavior is considered a bug. You'd probably find it in the changelog if you looked hard enough. Don't know about ksh.

csh and tcsh (with `$status` in place of `$?`) also say 0, but I bet nobody cares about that.

People with bigger shell collections are invited to test:

```
for sh in /bin/sh /bin/ksh /bin/bash /bin/zsh ...insert more shells here...; do
  echo -n "$sh "
  $sh -c 'false;true|echo $?'
done
```

Comment: so do you mean the `echo $?` show the value of previous command return value as below answer? but why my test result, it will always return "0"?

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed explanation and test! now I understand it.

Answer (score 6):

It does not have anything to do with `cat abc`, but with the previous command you executed. So the code you get when doing `cat abc | echo $?` is telling if the previous command in your history was successful or not.

From `man bash`:

> **Special Parameters**
>
> **?** - Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.

So when you do:

```
cat abc | echo $?
```

The `echo $?` refers to the previous command you used, not `cat abc`.

#### Example

```
$ cat a
hello
$ echo $?
0

$ cat aldsjfaslkdfj
cat: aldsjfaslkdfj: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

So

```
$ cat a
$ cat a | echo $?
0

$ cat aldsjfaslkdfj
cat: aldsjfaslkdfj: No such file or directory
$ cat a | echo $?
1
```

Comment: why my test is different with yours? my test bed is CentOS 6.4.     `-bash-4.1$ cat a   
 -bash-4.1$ echo $?   
0   
-bash-4.1$ cat a    
-bash-4.1$ cat a|echo $?   
0   
-bash-4.1$ cat abc   
cat: abc: No such file or directory   
-bash-4.1$ echo $?   
1   
-bash-4.1$ cat abc   
cat: abc: No such file or directory   
-bash-4.1$ cat abc | echo $?   
0   
cat: abc: No such file or directory`

Comment: Uhms, so you are getting `0` even though the previous command is a `cat` to a non-existing file. What is your system? I tried on `GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`, Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: yes, my test bed is CentOS 6.4, GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: I tried another test bed with bash version 4.2, it has the same result as you said, so now all is clear.

Answer (score 0):

echo $? will give output of previous command which you have executed before not output of piped command. So, you will always get echo $? as 0 even if command failed before pipe.

Answer (score 0):

You pipe the output from 'cat abc' to 'echo $?' which is not what you want.
You want to echo the exit code of 'cat'

```
cat abc; echo $?
```

is what you want. Or simply write it in two lines if you can.

Comment: thanks for response, you are right and I know that, I just want to know what happend to the pipeline.